# Replacement part for coal stove blower rheostat

Tags: electrical, hvac, fans, electric-motor, blower

I have an Alaskan coal stove and my blower rheostat broke this morning. I opened it up hoping to be able to fix the part instead of buying a whole new fan controller. Any motor controllers that I found online have two inputs and two outputs, while this part only has one of each. I don't really know anything about how the blower is electrically designed. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what kind of replacement part I need?

[image: Picture of rheostat]

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a standard A/C dimmer switch circuit:

http://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/potentiometer-w-switch-wiring-for-lamp.79664/

I'd imagine you could replace it with a standard A/C variable motor control like this one:

http://www.globalindustrial.com/p/hvac/exhaust-fans/in-line-duct-fans/kb-electronics-vari-speed-ac-motor-speed-control-kbwc-15-solid-state?infoParam.campaignId=T9F&gclid=CN-z8pGMtsoCFYM8aQodWAoOaQ

The 4-wire versions require you to connect the white wires in your box as well.

Alternatively, Harbor Freight and other sellers sell a replacement for this fan controller here:
http://www.harborfreight.com/router-speed-control-43060.html

All it is is a dimmer switch in a box with an extension cord.